# Meta community-wiki warning alert shouldn't contain anything about reputation

Tags: discussion, bug, meta, community-wiki, ask-question-form

I have just realized that when checking the "Community-wiki" checkbox on a Meta question, the alert says (***emphasis*** mine):

> Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?
>
> Doing so will remove explicit ownership **and you will no longer earn reputation for upvotes on it**. Once saved, this option cannot be unchecked without moderator assistance.

I thought we normally didn't receive rep (or lose it) for votes on Meta. The emphasized text should be removed from the alert because it only applies for regular SO, and could potentially confuse new users.

---

I have just found out that reputation is still tracked for badges like Mortarboard on Meta; it doesn't affect your reputation. Instead, it should probably say something like:

> Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?
>
> Doing so will remove explicit ownership and you will no longer earn reputation-based badges on Meta (for example, "Mortarboard") for votes on it. Once saved, this option cannot be unchecked without moderator assistance.

Comment: IIRC, internally the system does have reputation from meta votes, it's just that it doesn't show publicly. The reason I know this is because when you track yourself for the Mortarboard badge, you can see that it will give you how much meta rep you earned by 200.

Comment: @10Rep Then maybe it should be changed to say something like: "your reputation on the main site will not be affected"?

Comment: Yea, that seems like a better option.

Comment: You can also get tag badges for "non-community wiki answers" on meta.